# display results in jtable pagewise i.e. not using scroll bar to navigate

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The jtable I'm using fetches results from database. currently I have added scrollbars(vertical and horizontal). Just wanted to know that is it possible to display the results pagewise-say show 10 results per page. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to create/use a `TableModel` that only has `n` number of rows per "batch" and update the model each time you want to change pages.  You can use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to provide support of things like [pgup] and [pgdown] for example, which would move between "pages"

Comment: okay..any relevant tutorials or methods that u can suggest?

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as well as the key bindings.  You need to establish some system to update the `TableModel` each time you want to move between pages though

Comment: here are a few code examples in SSCCE/MCVE form about pagination in JTable, in two-three correct ways